# How to show tkinter text box without blocking interpreter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code to show Text on Pop up :

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
S = Scrollbar(root)
T = Text(root, height=4, width=50)
S.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
quote = """ My tesx
Devoutly to be wished."""
T.insert(END, quote)
mainloop(  )
```

But, dont want to block the main interpreter, How can I proceed ? (Should I use seperate process)  ?

Comment: Cannot test right now, but the best option is probably to start this in a thread. Like, put all your window creation in a function, then run `_thread.start_new_thread(create_window)`. Should do the trick.

Comment: all GUIs work different than text script. They have `mainloop` which have to run all the time to get events for system, sents events to widgets, updates widgets and draws widgets. You have buttons and `events` to run your code. There is also `root.after(milisecond, function_name)` to run periodically function. So main question is what do you want to do when pop up is displayed - maybe you have to `bind()` function to some `event`.

Comment: BTW: example [how to use after() to run code periodically to update clock](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

Comment: Nothing, Text is jut for me to read.
User should click on X for windows closing.